# How to send data from libgdx project to web?

Tags: libgdx

I would like to work on moving the json data from libgdx to my web server, but I am not sure how to do it. The method below was created by referring to libgdx's documentation.

```
private void httpPostJson(){
    final Json json = new Json();
    final String requestJson = json.toJson(requestObject);
    Net.HttpRequest request = new Net.HttpRequest("POST");
    final String url = "http://localhost:8080/data";
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setContent(requestJson);

    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            String responseJson = httpResponse.getResultAsString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            data = gson.fromJson(responseJson, Person.class);
            //'Person' is just sample class. data is class Person's object.
            data.StoreData("",1);//successed to receive json data from web server.
            //StoreData is just getter method.
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            Gdx.app.log("failed!");
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            Gdx.app.log("cancelled!");
        }
    });
}
```

It is possible to receive data transmitted from a web server.
But, this method can't send data to web server. 
Can you tell me how to move data from libgdx project to web server?

Comment: this is for sending POST or GET request, are you managing this requests in "http://localhost:8080/data"? it would be nice to see the server code in which you handle the request

Comment: If so, could you please tell me how to send the data to the web?

Answer (score 0):

This is the data transmitted to the web server:

```
final String requestJson = json.toJson(requestObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using the following Code (as you have more control over the request as opposed to using gdx.net), works like a charm, just don't execute on the main thread - body is your JSON as String

```
        URL url = new URL(<your url>);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
        if (body != null) {
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(body);
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }
        conn.connect();
        String s = stringFromStream(conn.getInputStream(), 4096);
```

Method stringFromStream:

```
    public static String stringFromStream(final InputStream is,
                                      final int bufferSize) {
    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        try {
            for (; ; ) {
                int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (rsz < 0)
                    break;
                out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return out.toString();
}
```